# Реализация кнопок опубликовать/удалить запись

Tags: php, mysql

Добрейший вечерочек. Не подскажете, как реализовать кнопки одобрения и удаления записи с сайта?
Я додумался только до такого:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name = "new_cat" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<?php
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['submit'])) {
    $sql = ("UPDATE `films` SET `fpublic` = '1' WHERE `id`=".$data['new_cat']);
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result ->execute();
}
?>
```

Цеплять по две формы на каждый пост как-то не логично. Да и страница работает не верно:
Нажимаешь на кнопку, страница перезагружается, все остается без изменений, перезагружаешь страницу сам, появляется окно о подтверждении повторной отправки данных, и вот тогда пост опубликовывается.

Так что как проще всего реализовать эти две кнопки для опубликовывания и удаления записи?

Comment: в примере указана только одна кнопка. опубликуйте весь код что затрагивается в вопросе.

Comment: Я показал на примере одной кнопки.

Comment: Зачем вам формы вообще? Ссылки с той же информацией не устраивают? На клиенте проверить уверенность действия (js onConfirm()), на сервере доступ к методам, и редирекст обратно к странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="?id=1">Обновить</a>
```

В обработчик

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Здесь делаете запрос БД
    header('Location: /'); // Переадресация на нужную страницу
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант мне подходит. Спасибо..

Answer (score 0):

Делайте POST на другую страницу. Там производите UPDATE и через

```
header("Location: ...");
```

возвращайте на исходную страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Может говорю не оптимальное решение, но самый адекватный вариант — это делать не формой. Делаешь 2 кнопки, т. к. разный смысл кнопок. Вешаешь обработчик на клики JavaScript или даже JQuery, как тебе больше нравится, и при помощи AJAX отправляешь на страничку PHP, там происходит нужная операция, делается проверка на адекватность и выдаётся ответ. Уже на твоей странице выводится в зависимости от этого ответа результат о успехе или неудаче...

Плюс того, что я говорю, в том, что ты будешь без перезагрузки контролировать всё, и результат будет максимально адекватен. Минус моего подхода — если вдруг магическим образом попался тот самый пользователь с отключённым JavaScript в браузере, то он не сможет ничего сделать (по мне это несущественно, в 95% случаев он включён), и плюсов больше чем минусов.

Comment: Вариант хороший, но аяксы мне не знакомы.